# Firefox Reality enter VR immersion mode without clicking vr button?

Tags: firefox, aframe, webvr

Can Firefox reality enter VR immersive mode without clicking VR button, or can it be clicked on simulation screen? How to simulate screen click in VR scene of Firefox reality?

i want to load the URL and go directly to immersive VR mode without any user action

thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. As per WebXR and WebVR specs immersive mode must be triggered by user action. That’s intentional to prevent sites to take over the screen without users consent.